# Install .NET Framework 4.0.2 with WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I am using WiX v3.7
There I have created my own Bootstrapper. Now, I am able to install .NET Framework 4  when it is not installed.

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />

<PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
  <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="..\..\Lib\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
              DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
              DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
</PackageGroup>
```

Now, my application needs .NET Framework 4.0.2. How can I test and install this if it is not available with WiX?
On which way can I test this? - and what does I have to do to install it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.0.2 update looks to be just another executable. Chain it after your Netfx4Full. You will need to provide all the detection and URL logic for the new 4.0.2 executable